# Spotfire - sum() over lookback

Tags: sum, calculated-columns, spotfire

I’m trying to sum the values in a column VAL for the last 14 days from T_DATE, by account.

My expression is

```
if([RND_FLG]=1 ,Sum([VAL]) over (Intersect([T_ACC],LastPeriods(14,[T_DATE]))),null)
```

9/10 the results are accurate, but this is not always the case.

Any help is appreciated.

Sample data below:

```
ALLDATE     T_ACC       VAL     14DAYVAL  
12/13/2016  1501313137  500000  500000  
12/15/2016  1501313137  800000  1300000  
12/19/2016  1501313137  500000  1800000  
12/20/2016  1501313137  500000  2300000  
12/21/2016  1501313137  500000  2300000  
12/22/2016  1501313137  500000  3300000  
12/30/2016  1501313137  200000  3500000
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting incorrect results when you have gaps in your dates. `LastPeriods()` isn't the same as n - days so it's aggregating over n number of rows versus days. You can normalize your data to have 1 row per date to get around this.

Comment: I've tried using the DateAdd function, (DateAdd("day",-14,[T_DATE])), to establish the cutoff date for each day,  but still wind up incorrect.  Does the below make sense?  if(([RND_FLG]=1), Sum([VAL]) over (Intersect([T_ACC], DateAdd('day', -14, [T_DATE]))), NULL))  Can you think of any alternatives for this?

Comment: For further clarification, I do not want to sum the value of every single row that occurred over the past 14 days, only the values that are considered "round" (have 5+ zeros), which is why there is the if statement of the rnd_flag in the above equation.  Thanks!

Comment: @LaurenFetky I think you are going to have to normalize your data or handle this in Python or TERR

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a rank column like Rank([T_DATE],[T_ACC]) Then you can sum using over intersect and lastperiods